# What is my local address on the router when connected through PPTP?

Tags: vpn, router, pptp

I have just set up my very first VPN this week allowing me to connect to work (this way, I get to work from home, which was worth the effort). As through magic, it now works, and I'm sending this question over my company's network. I'm connecting to a Synology disk station and my client is a Windows Vista machine.

My question stems from curiosity, and possibly misconception: what is the IP address I'm connected with on our network? Our company router is on 10.0.0.1, which I can now connect to (WNDR3700, V1.0.0.36 firmware). When I go to 'attached devices' there is no device that corresponds to any of my MAC addresses, nor an IP address I expected to be behind.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer to my own question.. I'll post it here in case somebody finds this page.

Once you connect through a VPN onto another network you will not be given a separate LAN address for that accessed network, instead your data packets will be sent to the device that acts as a VPN server on that network, which will then forward them to you.

This means there is no way to see on your router status list who is connected to your network through VPN.

There is also no MAC address for the computer for the same reason.